# Could injectors be used as an alternative to turbopumps in jet engines?

Tags: engine-design, fuel-systems

Could injectors be used instead of turbopumps in aeroengines? Are there jet engimes that already use them?
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injector

Comment: I assume you are talking about fuel. most engines I'm aware of do not use turbopumps for fuel, but rather positive displacement pumps like a gear pump.

Comment: An injector and a pump are not interchangeable. The pump moves the fuel, the injector is the point at which the fuel enters the combustion chamber. To my knowledge, turbopumps are used on rocket engines.